# Convolve function: Avoide 1px shifting to left top

Tags: delphi, image-processing, convolution

I am using a Convolve function from [swissdelphicenter.ch](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1704). The function looks good, but the problem is that the final image is shifted 1px to left top. This becomes more prominent when you convolve an image multiple times.

Turns out I can get through this by following modification, but the function isn't work if source and destination are the same image.

```
begin
  ...
  Result.Width := ABitmap.Width {- 2};
  Result.Height := ABitmap.Height {- 2};
  ...
  for LRow := 1 to ABitmap.Height - 3 do   //old val is 2
  ...
  LRowOut := Dst.ScanLine[LRow{ - 1}];
  ...
  LRowOut[LCol {- 1}].rgbtBlue  := trunc(LNewBlue);    
  LRowOut[LCol {- 1}].rgbtGreen := trunc(LNewGreen);
  LRowOut[LCol {- 1}].rgbtRed   := trunc(LNewRed);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: So keep a cache of a few scanlines.

Comment: Does this make function slower?

Comment: No, on the contrary. But perhaps a little more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

If source and destination are the same image, you are rewriting scanline with new (filtered) contents (using (i-1)th, i-th and (i+1)th ones to calculate new i-th)

So remember two upper scanlines - copy their contents with `Move` routine to TempRow1 and TempRow2 and use these TempRows in calculations.